# Best way to finish a wood mantle over a wood stove

Tags: wood, fireplace, stove

I was given a pine and cedar mantle that was built and finished with "tung oil finish". Can this be used as a mantle when wall temps are above 100 degrees?

Edit: the mantle was built by someone, not purchased

Answer (score 1):

Upon review of a datasheet it looks like the additives to tung oil finish are combustible at temps near what the stove would emit at it's mount point. I'm going to repurpose this to a shelf in a bedroom away from heat